# Drupal 7 Taxonomy term display page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to display my content in Alphabetical group for a specific content type.

What I did?

1. Added a vocabulary "Category"
2. Added a term(Myterm) inside this vocabulary.
3. Added a field in content type and put the relation with this vocabulary and the default option is the term name.

This is working fine. Now I want to show up the Myterm page the content alphabetical group. For your information I used Pathauto module to create the taxonomy term url. So my current url is domainname.com/MyTerm

This page showing the results which are belongs to MyTerm term. I want to just display the Alphabetical group and each group will contain the content whose title starting with this group. Please guys advice me how to implement this. If any contributed module is available, please advice. Thanks in advance.

e.g. Suppose my requirement is like below:

[A]
Amazing Video
A good tutorial
Award wining software
[B]
British Council
Be right back
[C]
Case discussion
Content privacy
....

Comment: 'Alphabetical group and each group will contain <b>the content</b> whose title st' In the line above the content means content type ?? Pls explain a little more about your requirements?

Comment: I would like to show https://drupal.org/glossary

Comment: Have you any idea, which module has been used for that?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you would like to achieve is like a glossary.

You can by default create a glossary with views. How to do this is best explained or shown in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18Ajtmstxsg).

If you want to show each of these on one page, i think you need to have some kind of a special field to group your results by. For this, try to the [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. Make a field where you grab the first letter of each term, and group by this (for example).

Comment: Hello. Are you sure your answer will stay useful if the video linked happens to be down or relocated (or became paid material)? For me it looks down even at the moment I write this.

Comment: Good point ... same for the module link. If do is down, the module cant be downloaded. I told him at least what he has to look for in views or what he is looking for.

Comment: Well, in [help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) there is this rule: *"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."* - could you please quote essential part of the video and write a sentence or 2 what exactly this module is supposed to do? Even if it's obvious for you and me, it might not be for newcomers.

Comment: Yes it is good but I want to implement like this https://drupal.org/glossary